# Raspberry Pi MAX31856 Thermocouple Temperature Reading Error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, temperature

I'm working with t-type thermocouple and needs to read the temperature data using python on Raspberry Pi 3. I used Adafruit MAX31856 to connect the thermocouple to the Pi and and tried to read it using [this module](https://github.com/johnrbnsn/Adafruit_Python_MAX31856).

I want to read the temperature for an extended period of time so I tried to print it out in a `while loop` However, anytime I run my code, I only get few 'correct' readings then the temperature resets to 0 until I re-run the code again - see the attached image.

[image]

I don't know what is causing this, and I don't think this is a connection problem since it prints the correct temperature when I re-run the code without touching the set-up.

Does anyone know why the reading is resetting to 0?

Here is my code:

```
from Adafruit_MAX31856 import MAX31856
import time

# Raspberry Pi software SPI configuration.
CLK = 4
CS  = 22
DO  = 17
DI  = 27
sensor = MAX31856(clk=CLK, cs=CS, do=DO, di=DI)

while True:
    temp = sensor.readTempC()
    print('Thermocouple Temperature: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp))
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: Try resetting sensor by putting `sensor = MAX31856(clk=CLK, cs=CS, do=DO, di=DI)` in the while loop.

Comment: That worked! Though I don't understand why. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting sensor by putting `sensor = MAX31856(clk=CLK, cs=CS, do=DO, di=DI)` in the while loop.